# Permanently killing the dGPU on a MacBook Pro, including on startup

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, hardware

I would like to permanently kill the discrete GPU on my 2011 MacBook Pro 15 so that it will always use the integrated GPU, including on startup.

(WHY? -- my 2011 15-inch MacBook Pro (2.3 i7 quad core;16RAM;2000SSD/AMD discrete GPU) had the GPU go bad two weeks after the warranty program expired. I called Apple support to ask them their advice on disabling the discrete GPU on boot, and they could not or would not give me information on the topic. Further, I was told that the computer is now considered "vintage" and that "Apple no longer produces the logic board" so I cannot get the computer repaired even out of pocket. Well...that seems rather strange since program to get the logic board replacement program ended on December 31, 2016 (so two weeks ago.) Now I am left with a computer that works perfectly except for the bad dGPU, which had it not been a turd and just died 15 days earlier I would have been able to get it fixed for free.)

I have found several threads on this forum, some of which are older. Thus far, this looks like the best method:
http://www.asyncro.com/2014/03/24/macbook-pro-discreate-graphics-card-issue-fix-updated/

Is this still the best methodology for doing this? Provided I ensure I do not delete the HD 3000 iGPU sys files, is this likely to kill the dGPU without throwing the computer into a safe mode loop? If not, what do you recommend? Thank you

Comment: check out https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/page-22#post-24835359   .  that's post #528 and is pretty simple.   the huge thread is because everyone is figuring out what to do, but don't worry overmuch.